# what essentials should I have for recording

Tags: microphone, audio-recording

I have Ableton and some Native Instruments plug-ins on Mac. I'd like to record for some educational music to put on YouTube. I would also like to take a first step into building a home recording studio.

What essentials do you recommend for recording? I'm interested in technologies surrounding audio recording (compressors, noise cancellers, etc..), but I'm not to well read on the subject yet and have not much time to travel too deeply.

What do I need?

Comment: I'm just interested in what people are using here and possibly turning me onto something I might've missed. I believe this is constructive

Comment: oh - in that case have a look down the posts in the Related sidebar to the right. There have been a number of posts on this topic - some are legacy, and should probably be closed, but loads of info there.

Comment: But WHAT are you recording? Vocal? Guitar? Piano? Synth, Harmonica? Bass? Gamelan? Bagpipes?  Do you have microphone(s)? Do you have a mixer or audio interface with mic input(s)?  Where exactly are you starting from?

Comment: *It really depends on your personal needs*, but as far as electronic equipment, you need a good *condenser* microphone (best at high-quality sound, as opposed to dynamic mics), or two if you need stereo (although there are ways to imitate stereo in mono recordings using reverb, or search Haas Effect). The good ones usually use XLR cable. (comment too long, see next)

Comment: You'll also need a good USB audio interface (converts analog audio to digital while preserving highest quality), which should have two XLR plugs for stereo (if you need stereo). Then of course a computer and software to record with. Feel free to ask me to explain anything, this topic really goes in depth.

Comment: The below link seems good. Not e that not all of the equipment it mentions is needed - headphone amps, mixers, etc... https://ehomerecordingstudio.com/recording-studio-equipment-list/